# DSL connection dropping when starting game

Tags: dsl

New connection set up last week - have called tech support, signal fine, sending out tech guy tomorrow - however i cant make sense of this

using Vista, 2wire connection 6mb ATT conn, wireless, i can browse website, stream video from my PC wirelessly to my xbox, watch Hulu in high res, connection seems fine

I load up World of Warcraft, i select Enter World and without fail my 2wire modem 'DSL' light goes red, my internet light goes out, im no longer connected, then after 10 or 15 seconds it works again, but game has kicked me

Noticed the same thing on opening or closing Utorrent as well

No other phones/devices plugged into the phone jacks in the apartment - why would joining a game cause my DSL to drop? i can only guess it throws a bunch of information to the server when i hit 'enter world' and that causes an issue that shuts my connection down

or my router hates me - all help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The major issue here is that the 2wire setup is both a router and adsl modem in one unit, if you haven't changed any advanced features on that unit we can try running [TCP Optimizer](http://www.vista-files.org/programs/speed-guide-inc/tcp-optimizer.html) for Vista.  Run the file then click optimize, save then reboot the pc.
The only time I have seen an issue similar to this it was because the pc was requesting too many half open connections and the router could not handle it.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would try is a different router, at least to try and rule that out.

Also some routers have problems with UPNP, try turning off that option in your router configuration to see if that does anything.